# Artifacts location for Azure DevOps release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Can we give Azure blob storage as artifacts location for Azure DevOps release pipeline?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can only use file shares and internal Azure Devops storage.

Reading:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops#arguments